# Python - Program That Prints Grade Using Nested If-Else Statements

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, parse-error, comparison-operators

I'm trying to create a program that prompts users to enter their grade, and then compares that value, x, in a series of nested If-Else statements:

```
x = int(input("What is your grade?"))
def grade(x):

if x >= 90:
        return "A"
    else:
        if x >= 80:
            return "B"
        else:
            if x >= 70:
                return "C"
            else:
                if x >= 60:
                    return "D"
                else:
                    return "F"

print( "Grade:", grade(x))
```

When I try to run this program, I get an error message:

```
ParseError: bad input on line 4
```

What's wrong with:

```
if x >= 90:
```

?

So far I haven't been able to get the dialogue box to show up asking for the user to enter their grade because of this error.

**EDIT**: After fixing indentation and using Elif

```
x = int(input("What is your grade?"))
def grade(x):

if x >= 90:
    return "A"

elif:
    x >= 80:
    return "B"
elif:
    x >= 70:
    return "C"
elif:
    x >= 60:
    return "D"
else:
    return "F"

print( "Grade:", grade(x))
```

Still gives me a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 7).
```

Comment: You don't need to indent that first `else`.

Comment: if the indentation is faithful to your code, no wonder why it crashes. And learn about `elif` !!!

Comment: Also, Python has no `ParseError` for source code errors (there is such an exception in the `xml.etree.elementtree` package, but you are not parsing XML here). Are you using some kind of online Python interpreter?

Comment: When I run it with another Python interface, the error message is clearly about the missed indentation.  With that line indented, the program appears to work.  Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: @Prune: indentation on the top-level lines is frequently mis-handled when posting. That said, this post lacks a [MCVE] so we can only speculate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm well aware of the problem.  The error is a couple of lines in, and the code *as given* does elicit a similar problem.  Also, fixing that one problem allows the code to run.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using Visualize Python....I fixed the indentation errors but now I'm getting a syntax error on line 7 (SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 7)). Please see this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/xKEeEU0M for my newest attempt.

Comment: Okay so "x >= 80", "x >= 70", etc, need to be on the same line as elif. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using nested else-if, I suggest you use `elif`

```
x = int(input("What is your grade?"))
def grade(x):
    if x >= 90:
            return "A"
    elif x >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif x >= 70:
            return "C"
    elif x >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

print( "Grade:", grade(x))
```

Input: `What is your grade? 10`

Output: `F`

And be careful about indented blocks!

And here is syntax if you are unclear with it.

```
if expression1:
   statements
elif expression2:
   statements
elif expression3:
   statements
else:
   statements
```

Comment: Yeah it was a misunderstanding of the syntax. I needed to put "x >= 80", "x >= 70" on the same line as "ellif" and fix the indentation. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! That's why I have added the syntax. :)

Answer (score 1):

Clean your code and fix those indention. Indention in python indicates a code block. All code inside the indention belongs to the upper parent.

if example:

```
 if(#argument here):
    ->indent #some line of code here
    ->indent #some line of code here
```

---

Equivalent:

```
if(#argument){
    #code block
    #code block
    #code block
}
```

---

Thus, to create a proper if-else:

if(#argument):
->indent code
else:
->indent code

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming it is a school assignment so I will keep it simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def grade(x):
    if  x >= 90:
        return 'A'
    elif x>=80:
        return 'B'
    elif x >= 70:
        return 'C'
    elif x >= 60:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'

try:
    x = int(input("What are your total marks? "))
    print("Grade: {}".format(grade(x)))
except ValueError as e:
    print("You did not enter valid total marks.")
    exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a indentation problem. The first if is into the function, so you need indent it. The first return can be less indented.

See:

```
x = int(input("What is your grade?"))
def grade(x):

    if x >= 90:
        return "A"
    else:
        if x >= 80:
            return "B"
        else:
            if x >= 70:
                return "C"
            else:
                if x >= 60:
                    return "D"
                else:
                    return "F"

print( "Grade:", grade(x))
```

In Python you need to pay atention on indentation.

Keep coding!